# Maximum number of edge in simple diagraph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations

Could anyone describe for me why the maximum number of edge in simple diagraph with no cycle is $\text{combination}(2,n)$?

My thought:

If you have $N$ nodes, there are $N - 1$ directed edges than can lead from it (going to every other node). Therefore, the maximum number of edges is $N \times (N - 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the underlying simple graph.  Certainly a simple (undirected) graph has at most $\binom{N}{2}$ edges.  If your directed graph is simple (no parallel arcs) and has more than $\binom{N}{2}$ edges then the underlying simple graph must have a parallel edge somewhere.  The parallel edge in the underlying simple graph must come from two arcs: $v\rightarrow w$ and $w\rightarrow v$, but that is a cycle.

Comment: I talk about simple directed graph with no cycle. so you means the last answer is Comb(2,n)?

Comment: What I showed was that if your digraph has no loops and no duplicate edges i.e. (v->w) and (v->w) again, then if it has more than N choose 2 edges then it must contain a directed cycle.  I suspect that you can get a better upper bound... but I'm not certain on that.

Comment: @TravisJ You can't: label the vertices $1$ through $n$, then add an edge $i\rightarrow j$ for each $i,j$ with $i<j$. This graph has no directed cycles and $\binom{n}{2}$ edges.

Comment: Dear @PerryElliott-Iverson, you means this is true that maximum number of edge in simple directed graph with no cycle is combination(2,n)?

Comment: Yes.  An acyclic digraph can't have any more... and it is possible that it has combination(2,n).

Comment: I'm sorry for lots of question, I think this is n-1?

Comment: It would be n-1 if you were talking about simple graphs... not digraphs.  In that case a tree (simple, connected graph with no cycles) has n-1 edges.